# ROR + Unable to install tiny_tds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Here I am trying to fetch data from `MS-SQL Server 2008` to my Rails application on Ubuntu 10. But I am unable to install `tiny_tds`. I follow the step given at github. But no response. Please guide me to setup correctly.

Used gem command :: `gem install tiny_tds`

This command as well :: `gem install tiny_tds –with-freetds-include=/usr/local/include/freetds –with-freetds-lib=/usr/local/lib`

Error :

```
Installing tiny_tds (0.4.5) with native extensions /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
looking for library directory /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/lib ... no
looking for library directory /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/lib/freetds ... no
looking for library directory /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/lib ... no
looking for library directory /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/lib/freetds ... no
looking for library directory /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib ... yes
checking for main() in -lsybdb... no
looking for library directory /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/freetds ... no
looking for library directory /home/.rvm/lib ... yes
checking for main() in -lsybdb... no
looking for library directory /home/.rvm/lib/freetds ... no
looking for library directory /home/lib ... no
looking for library directory /home/lib/freetds ... no
looking for library directory /usr/local/lib ... yes
checking for main() in -lsybdb... no
looking for library directory /usr/local/lib/freetds ... no
looking for library directory /usr/lib ... yes
checking for main() in -lsybdb... no
-----
Can not find FreeTDS's db-lib or include directory.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
    --enable-iconv
    --disable-iconv
    --enable-iconv
    --disable-iconv
    --with-freetds-dir
    --without-freetds-dir
    --with-freetds-include
    --without-freetds-include=${freetds-dir}/include
    --with-freetds-lib
    --without-freetds-lib=${freetds-dir}/lib
    --enable-lookup
    --disable-lookup
    --with-sybdblib
    --without-sybdblib
    --with-sybdblib
    --without-sybdblib
    --with-sybdblib
    --without-sybdblib
    --with-sybdblib
    --without-sybdblib
looking for library directory /usr/lib/freetds ... no
looking for library directory /usr/local/ruby/lib ... no
looking for library directory /usr/local/ruby/lib/freetds ... no


Gem files will remain installed in /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/tiny_tds-0.4.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/tiny_tds-0.4.5/ext/tiny_tds/gem_make.out
    from /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each'
    from /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `build_extensions'
    from /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `install'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:101:in `block in install'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:78:in `preserve_paths'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:91:in `install'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:57:in `block in run'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you get when installing the gem?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Did you install freeTDS prior to install the gem?

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev
```

Then

```
gem install tiny_tds
```

Comment: you saved my day :)

Comment: Those using CentOS can run `yum install freetds-devel -y`

Answer (score 45):

*The answer above is correct, this is just an additional note for those mac folks that prefer homebrew*

It command is essentially the exact same:

```
brew install freetds
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394476/unable-to-gem-install-tiny-tds-os-x-mavericks

Comment: `gem install tiny_tds -- --with-freetds-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/freetds/1.2.21`

Answer (score 7):

As ar3 says, the answer above is correct.  For those on CentOS, the RPM is freetds-devel, not freetds-dev (in case you're as soft with sysadmin as I am).

```
yum install freetds-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

For mac users first install `freetds` by `gem install tiny_tds`

then get the freetds path by `ls /opt/homebrew/Cellar/freetds`

my version is `1.3.10`

then

```
 gem install tiny_tds -- --with-freetds-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/freetds/1.3.10
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on a Mac, except Step 1 was:
`homebrew install freetds`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

Download freetds from following link and install it

[freetds download link](https://sources.voidlinux.eu/freetds-1.00.23/)

Install with following instructions:

```
cd /home/user/Downloads/
tar -zxvf freetds-1.00.23.tar.gz
```

Then

```
cd freetds-1.00.23/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

After freetds installation complete, try with `bundle install`

This will solve freetds dependency issue.