# Unable to `gem install tiny_tds` OS X Mavericks

Tags: rubygems, homebrew, tiny-tds

### The Error

> $ sudo gem install tiny_tds
>
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error installing tiny_tds:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>
> checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
>
> checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... yes
>
> checking for sybfront.h... yes
>
> checking for sybdb.h... yes
>
> checking for tdsdbopen() in -lsybdb... no

---

### HomeBrew

The above error occurs even after a

> $ brew install freetds

---

### Manual Installation

> $ tar zxf freetds-stable.tgz
>
> $ cd freetds-0.91
>
> $ ./configure
>
> $ make
>
> $ sudo make install

---

It appears to be missing the following file in `/usr/local/lib/`:

- `libsybdb.so`

Instead I have the following files:

- `libsybdb.a`
- `libsybdb.dylib`
- `libsybdb.la`

---

### Research

- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/24550
- [ROR + Unable to install tiny_tds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525109/ror-unable-to-install-tiny-tds)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I solved this problem by explicitly specifying the 64 bit architecture:

```
$ brew install freetds
$ sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install tiny_tds
```

The reason is that during the gem building process, mkmf will try to look for 32 bit version of freetds, which is not available. The error message in `mkmf.log` said:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libsybdb.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libsybdb.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_tdsdbopen", referenced from:
      _t in conftest-a13287.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Comment: This worked beautifully on El Capitan and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I didn't need to force 64 bit, but simply installing `freetds` solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

As I posted at [Homebrew / TinyTDS / FreeTDS bundle error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997722/homebrew-tinytds-freetds-bundle-error/70270949#70270949), in addition to `brew install freetds`, you may also need to configure bundler to know where to find freetds.

For example (depending where exactly homebrew installed freetds):

```
bundle config set --global build.tiny_tds --with-freetds-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/freetds/1.3.3
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

This was resolved by simply adding `/opt/chef/embedded/bin` to my `$PATH`

> $ sudo nano ~/.bashrc

---

**File Contents after change**

> export PATH="/opt/chef/embedded/bin:$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

---

**Update `$PATH`**

> $ source ~/.bashrc

---

**Install the gem (Make sure you've install `freetds` using one of the above methods)**

> $ sudo gem install tiny_tds

---

***SPECIAL NOTE:* This assumes you've installed the chef**

> $ curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash

Reference:

- http://www.getchef.com/chef/install/

Apparently the command to install is below:

> $ sudo gem install tiny_tds -- --with-freetds-include=/usr/local/freetds/include --with-iconv-include=/opt/chef/embedded/include --with-freetds-lib=/usr/local/freetds/lib